# Android: Find song with given name?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I am trying to play the song form the device  where the partial name of the song  given by the user.
Like if song named as "demosong.mp3" and if user serch the "demo" in textbox then "demosong.mp3" has to play.

Here my code goes:

```
    fileList=getfile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getAbsolutePath()));
            String  
          ss=fileList.toString();
          chk="Song Name i.e.demo";
          String direc,totpath,root1;
          root1=file21;
          direc="";
          name="";  
          String fla="True";
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(this); 



                    if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
                        direc="";
                        direc=fileList.get(i).getName();

                        //textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        name=direc+"//"+fileList.get(i).getName();
                        String  name1=name.toLowerCase();

                            if(name1.contains(chk))
                            {

                                String pth,nnn;




                                    Uri myUri11 = Uri.parse(pth);
                                 mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                    try 
                                    {
                                        mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),myUri11);
                                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } catch (IOException e) 
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    try {
                                        mPlayer.prepare();
                                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                    mPlayer.start();


                                    break;
                            }
                             else if(r[0].compareTo("stop")==0){

                                mPlayer.stop();
                                mPlayer.release();

                      }
                      else if(r[0].compareTo("pause")==0){

                          mPlayer.pause();                
                          mPlayer.release();
                          }


                    }





                }


                }


          }
          catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
    }
```

CODE TO CHECK EXTENSION OF FILE

```
public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);

            } else {
                if ( listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp3"))

                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

}

THANKS

Comment: instead of name1.contains(chk) use name1. startsWith(chk)

Comment: what's the issue is it matching or not? Is it going into if or not? What's exactly you entering in text box?

Comment: i am giving the some text of the song which i want to play ie:if song is "Art of living Om.mp3 and if i enter 'of living' in textbox" then the song has to be play but its going into if condition if the directory does not contain the song with the part of entered contents

Comment: Is there a question here somewher?